# What are these constructions similar to a pushout and pullback called?

Tags: category-theory

Apparently, a colimit also reverses the index category. So what are these called?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I only recognize two compositions $f\circ g$, $f\circ h$ on the right above and again two composition $g\circ f$,$h\circ f$ on the left down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just the existence of compositions of morphisms. Let's take the top right one, for instance. From the left vertex, you have an arow going to the lower vertex and then up to the top vertex. This induces an arrow from the left vertex to the top vertex. That's composition of morphisms. Same with the other three dotted arrows.